# SVN permissions for a single file

Tags: svn, permissions

Is it possible in SVN to set write permission for a single file, while all the rest of the repository is read only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible to set permissions on file level.
You either can use a pre-commit hook, or if you use svn 1.6,
you can move the file into a new directory and place a **file external** in your old directory. You can then modify the permissions on the new directory.

Note that file externals are working only on text files. binary files are not supoorted at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is the [pre-commit hook script](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html).

Answer (score 1):

you could try doing it with apache location if your accesing via webdav

Comment: Not really a solution when you work in a corporate environment. I have only access to the authz file.