# Modifying subversion file permissions

Tags: svn, version-control

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371824/svn-permissions-for-a-single-file) but it does not help me. I checked in a file without the executable permission and now, every time I branch or checkout, the file is not executable.

Some other files are indeed saved as executable. I'm guessing that it's because they had the executable bit during first check in--at least that's what my testing leads me to believe.

Does anyone know of a better way to modify (or even at least view) the permissions that subversion has for a file or folder?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use [svn propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html) as follows:

```
svn propset svn:executable ON executable_file
```

Then perform `svn commit`.